# Where the shaded region is added to the perimeter

Tags: geometry, circles, area

I have some problems finding the perimeter of the unshaded region as the picture below. $PQ = QR = PS$ is $5$ cm. $SR$ is $11$ cm. The radius of the circle is $1.2$ cm.

Perimeter of the trapezium:
$5\times3 + 11 = 26$ cm

Perimeter of shaded circle:
$2\times\pi\times(1.2) = 2.4\times\pi$ cm

Perimeter of unshaded region:
$26 + 2.4\times\pi = 33.5 $cm

My question is why the perimeter of the shaded circle is added to the perimeter of trapezium instead of subtracting it ? I fully understand if for the area of unshaded region, the area of trapezium minus the area of circle, Why not for perimeter?

[image: n]

Answer (score 1):

The perimeter is the boundary between a region and its complement.  If a region has a hole in it, the perimeter of the hole is a boundary between the region and its complement, so that counts positively in the boundary of the region.